# How to make iOS UIViewController as singleton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, singleton

I have two `UIViewController`, RootViewController and SecondViewController.

SecondViewController Connect to Server, and now I go back to RootViewController (`UINavigationController`), but when I turn to SecondViewController from `RootViewController`, there is a new SecondViewController.

How could I turn to the old SecondViewController?

I used singleton, but when I go back to RootViewController,I can not turn to SecondViewController again.

Comment: Do not use singletons for this. That's a terrible idea.

Comment: You should propably create some helper class to do this, like rmaddy said: Do not use singletons for this!

Comment: Is there any Demo?If I use helper class,how to connect to the UIViewController?Helper class is singleton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AppDelegate.h
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *sc;
AppDelegate.m
_sc = nil;
RootViewController.m
- (IBAction)tiaozhuian:(UIButton *)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if(appDelegate.sc == nil)
    {
    appDelegate.sc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:appDelegate.sc animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.sc);
    }else{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:appDelegate.sc animated:YES];
    }
}
```

//Define a global variable sc, and sc = nil, sc = appDelegate.sc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"]when first turn to SecondView , return to RootView and turn to SecondView again whether the sc is nil, and if not,turn to SecondView.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a MainViewController and inside MainViewController you should init RootViewController (or ServerViewController) and SecondViewController.

When you tap on the back button a view should simply be hidden. More if you could share the code.

Answer (score -2):

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *sc;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
_sc = nil;
```

RootViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)tiaozhuian:(UIButton *)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if(appDelegate.sc == nil)
    {
      appDelegate.sc=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:appDelegate.sc animated:YES];
      NSLog(@"%@",appDelegate.sc);
    } else {
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:appDelegate.sc animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Define a global variable sc, and sc = nil, sc = appDelegate.sc =
`[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondViewController"]`.

When first turn to SecondView , return to RootView and turn to SecondView again whether the sc is nil, and if not, turn to SecondView.

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain how your answer solves the question.